# Raised PHP7.0-fpm capacity, still overloads

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, php7

I'm at a loss here. I run a few dozen servers with all different amounts of traffic. As the traffic increased over time, some servers started crashing (502/503 errors) and I figured it was due the php configuration which was unchanged from default.

For instance, I set the config in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` as follows, based on the hardware of the server:

```
pm.max_children = 70
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 500
```

And after these edits, it was smooth sailing for all servers; no more spikes, no more errors. Until today I get a downtime pushmessage and `/var/log/upstart/php7.0-fpm.log` reads:

```
[09-Jul-2018 08:51:01] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 18 idle, and 39 total children
[09-Jul-2018 08:52:03] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 14 idle, and 52 total children
[09-Jul-2018 08:52:04] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 19 idle, and 58 total children
[09-Jul-2018 08:53:06] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (70), consider raising it
```

Which is essentially the same error I got before, but with higher numbers. I think I'm missing some other related setting to keep this in bounds, but, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no other related settings.
Either increase limits further or optimize the PHP application or add more servers.
Depending on traffic/PHP application, it could be normal to have lots of workers or not

Comment: Ok thanks, that confirms my suspicion that when a few crawlers, API calls and cron all fire at the same time, it starts to choke. Just needed to be sure I didn't overlook anything, in which case I'll go spread out all these jobs.